# TLS 1.2 no Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tls

Alguém sabe como configurar para a aplicação Java usar o TLS 1.2 ?
Essa configuração é feita na aplicação Java ou no servidor ?

Estou usando Spring 3.1

Obrigado

Comment: Olá! Qual versão do Java? O Java 8 e algumas versões do 7 já vem com suporte habilitado, por padrão, ao TLS 1.2.